# Where is the 'end' missing?

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax, terminal

Sorry if it so obvious, I'm a quite noob at ruby (actually, coding in general). This code intents to name chemical compounds, but after I've add the "funcao_organica" method, i got this output:

*main.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end*

I think I'd set all 'ends' in fine place. Whats wrong with this script?

```
class Molecule

  carbon_number_name = { 1 => 'met', 2 => 'et', 3=> 'prop', 4 => 'but', 5 =>'pent', 6 =>'hex'}; bonds = {1 => 'ano', 2 => 'eno', 3 => 'ino'}
  x = Molecule.new

  def molecule(hidrogen, carbon_numbers)
    @carbon_numbers = carbon_numbers
    @hidrogen = hidrogen
    if hidrogen ==  2*(carbon_numbers) 
      return 2
    elsif hidrogen == 2*(carbon_numbers) + 2
      return 1
    elsif hidrogen == 2*(carbon_numbers) - 2
      return 3
    else 
      puts 'this molecule does not exist'

  end  

  def funcao_organica(carbon_main_chain, oxigen)
    @carbon_main_chain = carbon_main_chain
    @oxigen = oxigen 
    if hidrogen == (2*(carbon_numbers) + (carbon_main_chain) - 1) &&  carbon_numbers > 2 
      print 'ol'
    end
  end

  c = 5 ; h = 14 ; r = 5; o = 1
  puts carbon_number_name[c] + bonds[x.molecule(h,c)] + x.funcao_organica(r,o)

end
```

Comment: You're missing an `end` in your `molecule` method.  If you indent/format your code, it's much easier to spot these kinds of issues.

Comment: Use https://atom.io/packages/linter-ruby-lint or https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-ruby

Answer (score 3):

The `end` is missing in the molecule method.  There's should be an `end` to end the if statement:

```
def molecule(hidrogen, carbon_numbers)
    @carbon_numbers = carbon_numbers
    @hidrogen = hidrogen
    if hidrogen ==  2*(carbon_numbers) 
      return 2
    elsif hidrogen == 2*(carbon_numbers) + 2
      return 1
    elsif hidrogen == 2*(carbon_numbers) - 2
      return 3
    else 
      puts 'this molecule does not exist'
    end #closing the if statement

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have an `end` in

```
def molecule(hidrogen, carbon_numbers)
  @carbon_numbers = carbon_numbers
  @hidrogen = hidrogen
  if hidrogen ==  2*(carbon_numbers) 
    return 2
  elsif hidrogen == 2*(carbon_numbers) + 2
    return 1
  elsif hidrogen == 2*(carbon_numbers) - 2
    return 3
  else 
    puts 'this molecule does not exist'
  end  # <<<=== HERE
end
```

The last `end` is closing the method definition. You need another `end` to close the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

A big problem here is your particular coding style, especially the unnecessary
use of `;` to combine multiple lines together and the irregular indentation
used in the code. Keep things simple, clean, and orderly to avoid making
elementary syntax errors. Mistakes should be visually obvious as a break in
the usual patterns.

Here's a refactored version of your code:

```
class Molecule
  # Define CONSTANT values for those things that are used more than once
  # within various methods inside your class.
  CARBON_NUMBER_NAME = {
    1 => 'met',
    2 => 'et',
    3=> 'prop',
    4 => 'but',
    5 => 'pent',
    6 => 'hex'
  }
  BONDS = {
    1 => 'ano',
    2 => 'eno',
    3 => 'ino'
  }
  ELEMENT = {
    c: 5,
    h: 14,
    r: 5,
    o: 1
  }

  def molecule(hydrogen, carbon_numbers)
    @carbon_numbers = carbon_numbers
    @hydrogen = hydrogen

    case hydrogen
    when 2*(carbon_numbers) 
      2
    when 2*(carbon_numbers) + 2
      1
    when 2*(carbon_numbers) - 2
      3
    else
      # Raise an error if one occurs, don't just print something.
      raise 'this molecule does not exist'
    end
  end  

  def funcao_organica(carbon_main_chain, oxigen)
    # NOTE: carbon_numbers needs to be defined here, but it isn't,
    #       and @carbon_numbers is only defined if molecule() is
    #       called previously. This could be an issue.
    @carbon_main_chain = carbon_main_chain
    @oxigen = oxigen 

    if hydrogen == (2*(carbon_numbers) + (carbon_main_chain) - 1) &&  carbon_numbers > 2 
      print 'ol'
    end
  end
end

# Move code outside the body of the class definition
x = Molecule.new

puts Molecule::CARBON_NUMBER_NAME[ELEMENT[:c]] + Molecule::BONDS[x.molecule(ELEMENT[:h],ELEMENT[:c])] + x.funcao_organica(ELEMENT[:r],ELEMENT[:o])
```